# Excel formulas. Foreign key

Tags: sql, excel

I have two tables:

```
# BILLING PERIOD TABLE
+-----------+
| id | value|
-------------
|  1 | some |
|  2 | else |
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

and

```
# ELECTRICITY TABLE

+----------------------------+
| billing period| value      |
------------------------------
| 1             | desired val|
| 2             |            |
| 3             |            |
```

And I would like to write formula that takes and compares `billing period id` with `billing period` and puts `value` from `billing period table` to the cell `value` next to `billing period`

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was suggested by @Tim Williams, `VLOOKUP()` is the way to go.

Assuming you've named the first table `BILLING_PERIOD`, and the second table `ELEC`, and using your headers, in the `value` column you would use:

```
=VLOOKUP([@[billing period]],BILLING_PERIOD,2,FALSE)
```

An extra touch can be to surround it with `IFERROR`, to insert some default value if the id isn't in the table, instead of showing a `#N/A` error.

EDIT: just noticed that it wasn't mentioned, but my assumption was that you are talking about two excel tables, if that was not the meaning, please be more specific.